# XPages: Dynamically populate Navigator Control

Tags: dynamic, view, xpages, navigator

I need to create links of available views in database on Navigator Control. I  did not find any computed formula area for that control. Just like we use code for combobox:

```
var v = database.getViews();
var a = []
for(var i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
   a[i] = v[i].getName()
}
return a
```

After achieving that, the select view will display by Dynamic View Panel of ext library. 
Please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

-MAK

Comment: When you say links for available views in database. Do you mean a link to each xPage displaying a view or just a entry for each view in the database directing the user to the middle of nowhere?

Comment: Single Xpage display all available views [name of views] in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a navigation entry for each view in you database using the `<xe:repeatTreeNode>` in the `<xe:navigator>`:

```
<xe:navigator id="outline" expandable="true">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
    <xe:repeatTreeNode loaded="true" indexVar="index" var="crrView" value="#{javascript:return database.getViews();}">
        <xe:this.children>
            <xe:basicLeafNode label="#{javascript:crrView.getName();}" loaded="true">
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.children>
    </xe:repeatTreeNode>
</xe:this.treeNodes>
</xe:navigator>
```

This code will generate a  in you navigation for each view in your Database. You can use the variable `crrView` in the `<xe:basicleafNode>` to get current element of the Vector returned by `database.getViews()` in the loop.

You can also use other elements then the `<xe:basicLeafNode>` in the `<xe:repeatTreeNode>.`Select the RepeatNode in the NavigationItems window of the navigatior control and click on add Child.

Comment: Thanks Michael Saiz! your code work for me. One more thing, I add below code in SELECTED property of childnode, but it is not working: if(viewScope.viewName == context.getSubmittedValue()){
 true;
}
else{
 false
}

Comment: When I click on view name in Navigator Control, it passes the value to viewScope variable (viewName). On partial refresh my Dynamic View Panel display this view. All that stuff working perfectly but on my Navigator control there is no identification (selected) which view is active on dynamic panel.

Comment: add following code to your selected field: `selected="#{javascript:crrView.getName().equals(context.getSubmittedValue());`if you want to have one of you items selected by default you could add something like if(context.getSubbmittedValue ===null) ...