# XPAGES: populate a navigator control with unique values from a column view

Tags: xpages

New to XPAGES here. How do i populate a navigator control with unique values from a column value. Thanks in advance.

did something similar to this link: 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979160/xpages-dynamically-populate-navigator-control)

unfortunately i get something like this:
Value1, Value2, Value3
Value1, Value2, Value3
Value1, Value2, Value3

instead of:
Value1 
Value2 
Value3

Comment: did something similar to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979160/xpages-dynamically-populate-navigator-control 

unfortunately i get something like this:
[Value1, Value2, Value3]
[Value1, Value2, Value3]
[Value1, Value2, Value3]

instead of:
Value1
Value2
Value3

Comment: Show us some code please

Answer (score 0):

look like you populate for every entry every column value, perhaps you have to select just one column. But Per has right, please show us some code please.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of pulling my hair i got it figured out. Code is pretty much similar to the link embedded above. Thanks folks